# Removing lines through symbols in legend in r

Tags: r, plot, legend

How can I remove the lines that intersect the symbols in an r legend? Have looked through ?legend but can't seem to find an answer..

```
plot.new()

legend("top",ncol=1,c("Mound reef (M)","Spur and Groove (SG)",
    "Rubble Fields (RF)","Coral Walls (CW)","Mounds and rubble fields (MR)",
    "Mounds, Monostand walls and Rubble (MMR)"),pch=3:8, title="Reef Types", 
    cex=1, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add  `lty=NULL`

```
plot.new()
legend("top",ncol=1,c("Mound reef (M)","Spur and Groove (SG)",
                      "Rubble Fields (RF)","Coral Walls (CW)",
                      "Mounds and rubble fields (MR)",
                      "Mounds, Monostand walls and Rubble (MMR)"),
       pch=3:8, title="Reef Types",cex=1,lwd=2, lty=NULL)
```

**EDIT**

Deleting `lwd=2` should suffice as pointed out by Josh O'Brien, so, your code should be:

```
plot.new()
legend("top",ncol=1,c("Mound reef (M)","Spur and Groove (SG)",
                      "Rubble Fields (RF)","Coral Walls (CW)",
                      "Mounds and rubble fields (MR)",
                      "Mounds, Monostand walls and Rubble (MMR)"),
       pch=3:8, title="Reef Types",cex=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I couldn't figure that out! :)

Comment: Hmm. Your code actually prints lines for me. (Using R-devel on Windows XP).

Comment: It worked well using Rstudio on Ubuntu, but just edited my answer taking into account your comment and your answer as well.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the symbols altogether, and also avoid wasting space on the left of the legend? If colours are used to distinguish multiple types of data point in the main plot, then colour is sufficient in the legend text and there is no need for any symbols (nor lines) in the legend

Answer (score 3):

You are only getting those lines because you specified `lwd=2`, which *tells* the `legend()` function that you want "line width=2". If you don't want lines, just drop the `lwd=` argument.

Comment: In spite of `lwd` set the line width (as you can see in `?par`) it also set the width of any symbol plotted, in this case it sets the width of the legend symbols. You can set `lwd=5` and `lty=NULL` and you'll get a wider symbol in your legend.

Comment: I'd control symbol size and symbol line width with the `pt.cex` and `pt.lwd` arguments.